# Deriving a constant in a probability mass function

Tags: probability, self-study, poisson-distribution

> Let $Y_1, . . . , Y_n$ be a random sample from a zero-truncated Poisson distribution with probability
>   mass function:
>
> $p_Y (y|λ) = k\frac{λ^ye^{-y}}{y!},$
>   $k > 0, λ > 0, y = 1, 2, . . . ,$
>   where k is an unknown constant.

I know that the sum of a probability mass function is 1, but I do not know how to use this information to find $k$.

Comment: You need to sum the series. However, your formula for the pmf is wrong!

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to do this, but thank you for confirming what I had suspected!

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=truncated+poisson+distribution for more.

Comment: @Clong123 could you sum it if it wasn't truncated?